# Core Data - get date of the last update of object`s property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I`m working on the caching functionality for a project. The data is downloaded from server and then saved to the Core Data storage as NSManagedObjects with specific properties. I wonder if there is a way to know when was the last update of the object **property's** value (I must track properties, not the whole objects, because they may be updated separately).

For example, lets assume I have an object called Report with the following properties:

```
NSManagedObject Report:
- reportName;
- reportAssignee;
- reportInfo;
- reportId;
```

I want to download data for Report from server, but I select only reportName and reportId fields. So I save received information to the object and here is what we have now:

```
NSManagedObject Report:
- reportName - MyReport;
- reportAssignee - not updated;
- reportInfo - not updated;
- reportId - fbbcc939393-sdfsjd49340.
```

How can I know that properties reportName and reportId were updated on 04-02-2015 and that properties reportDate, reportAssignee, reportInfo weren`t updated yet at all?

Of course it is possible to create duplicate properties with last update date for every property in the object but I hope there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I would keep `reportDate` as a timeStamp instead of a date object. Then I would only set the `reportDate` if all properties are retrieved from server. This field should only be getting set if you know the full object information has been retrieved. Otherwise you'll have to track one timestamp for each value (or keep track of two reportDates - one for name/id, and one for assignee/info).

Comment: There is a misunderstanding - reportDate is not the property in which I want to store the date of the last update, it is just an example property. I better remove it from question. My question is exactly about tracking each value in object. Storing only one date when object was fully updated will not help me at all.

Comment: when WHO updated the entity? your own app? then why would you download it?

Comment: The app just shows data. Data could be changed on the server side. So I must update it in the app once in 24 hours. And once again - there is a possibility to download not the whole object with all properties, but only few properties which are necessary at the moment. I can update only reportName and reportInfo. So I need a mechanism which could let me know that another properties weren`t updated yet or that some property was updated more than 24 hours ago and should be downloaded from server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the best bet in such situation is to create one new property in object:

```
NSManagedObject Report:
...
- (id) updateInfo;
```

And store there an NSDictionary where key is object_property_name and value is the date when this property was updated. So if we download reportName property for Report object from server and save this data - we should add key NSStringFromSelector(reportName) with value "04-02-2015" to the dictionary in updateInfo property.